# Intended purpose of hiding a base class' explicit interface implementation without warning?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism

Imagine these specifications are from an external dll. A class that implements an interface explicitly:

```
public interface IDebug
{
    string GetImportantInfo();
}
public class ExternalClass : IDebug
{
    public void DoSomethingImportant()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something important was done...");
    }
    string IDebug.GetImportantInfo() //Explicit implementation
    {
        DoSomethingImportant();
        return nameof(ExternalClass);
    }
}
```

Then this one is from internal code, where you know you need to implement the interface:

```
public class Debug : ExternalClass, IDebug
{
    public string GetImportantInfo()
    {
        return nameof(Debug);
    }
}
```

Now when I'm calling the `Debug`'s `GetImportantInfo()` method from the subclass, the explicit implementation in the superclass is not called:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDebug test = new Debug();
    var impInfo = test.GetImportantInfo();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(impInfo); //"Debug"
}
```

And the only slight hint I seem to get is that I don't get a compile error when adding the `IDebug` interface to the `Debug`class, without implementing the method:

```
public class Debug : ExternalClass, IDebug
{
}
```

Why is there no compile warning when you overwrite a superclass's implementation like this? If the base class implements it implicitly, I get a compile warning telling me to use the `new` keyword. But using the `new` keyword to overwrite an explicitly implemented method gives a compile warning:

> The member 'Program.Debug.GetImportantInfo()' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.

Is there an intended purpose for this, or is this a bug? If it's intended, what is the official reasoning?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be inheriting from any class without fully understanding it in the first place. Knowing what interfaces the base class implements (directly or not) seems like a reasonable thing to expect. Considering this and knowing how C#'s *interface re-implementation* works should be enough to avoid the warning

Comment: Also, the warning you get when the interface is implemented implicitly in the base class has little to do with interface implementation at all; its simply good old method hiding.

Comment: You're of course free to have that opinion. But I essentially equate your advice to "just don't make mistakes". Making the assumption that _everyone_ is infallible, is an impossible expectation to me. Being in a hurry or being forgetful are two normal use cases where this could happen. And suddenly you could spend a long time trying to debug the unexpected behavior. I don't see a difference between the need for the "good old method hiding" and this.

Comment: @Aske.B again, because the method hiding warning is due to the fact that you have two identical methods. It has nothing to do with interfaces. When one is implemented explicitly you stop having two identical methods and there is no method hiding to begin with. You are expecting a warning in one case based upon the false belief that the warning in the other case is due to the same reason, and its not.

Comment: I'm confused by the premise of the question. Is the question premised on the idea that you're deriving from a base class and *you don't know that the base class implements an interface*?  You are *required* to know that! You are required to know *everything* about the *public surface area* of a base class because *that becomes the public surface area of the derived class*, which you are responsible for *documenting*! The set of (public) interfaces implemented is part of the public surface area.

Comment: Can you give us some context as to why `//Explicit implementation` was used to start with? That might help us better understand where you are coming from.

Comment: @EricLippert Ditto. Said that a few times already but apparently the OP thinks it isn't necessary.

Comment: @InBetween: Indeed; if the claim is that *the work necessary to safely use a base class is onerous*, then I have an easy solution: if it hurts when you do that, *don't do that*. Write your own base class, or share functionality by composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Now, as for the note about the "missing `new`" warning: that's intended to ameliorate a brittle base class failure. But I'm not seeing a brittle base class failure scenario here that would justify a similar warning. Is there one?

Comment: I believe it was a base class called `MapRenderer` in Xamarin, implementing `IOnMapReadyCallback` - but it didn't implement that interface before he updated to the newer Xamarin version. I think that's probably just bad design from Xamarin's part, but scapegoating leads nowhere. I just asked this question because I was unaware of this behavior, and it stroke me as odd that this could happen, when it's something the compiler could have warned about.

Comment: @AskeB.: Sure, but where's the *brittle base class failure* in that scenario? Your complaint is basically "my derived class didn't change its behaviour when a base class changed its public surface area".  **MISSION ACCOMPLISHED**. C# was carefully designed so that common but hard-to-notice changes to base classes would not change behaviour in derived classes, and you got that. You want a warning that says "everything is still working like it did yesterday", and that's not a useful warning.

Comment: Put another way: you would not expect a warning if you created a method of the same name as a *private* member of a base class, right? Explicitly implemented interface methods can be thought of as private implementation details of the base class. If the base class wants to keep that private, and it doesn't change behaviour in the derived class, what's the problem? If the base class authors thought you should be warned for overriding their method accidentally then they would have made it public.

Comment: @EricLippert but as I understand it, the derived class _did_ change behavior. I don't know my colleague's implementation exactly but since he was calling a function himself, that the base class suddenly also called, he now got his own implementation called twice. And when he removed his own call, the base class was now suddenly calling his subclass implementation. I don't agree with the private member example, since that behavior is unchanged whatever you do. A base class can't call a derived class' private members directly.

Comment: If there's a brittle base class scenario that I don't know about, I'd love to hear details. I have a fondness for such scenarios. If you have a small repro please post more details; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using a little known feature of the language: *interface re-implementation*:

```
public class Debug : ExternalClass, IDebug
{
    public string GetImportantInfo()
    {
        return nameof(Debug);
    }
}
```

Why are you redeclaring that `Debug` implements `IDebug` if `ExternalClass` already does? You are re-implementationing the interface, and becuase you are doing such thing, you get no warning; the compiler assumes you know what you are doing.

If you want the behavior you seem to want, simply *don't re-implement the interface*:

```
public class Debug : ExternalClass
{
    public string GetImportantInfo()
    {
        return nameof(Debug);
    }
}
```

> If the base class implements it implicitly, I get a compile warning telling me to use the new keyword.

This warning has nothing to do with interface implementation. The warning is simply due to method hiding, you have two methods with the same signature; `IDebug` is a non factor here, you could put it out of the equation and you'd still get the same warning.

> In my colleague's case, he said he had to implement both the base class and the interface because it was an event-based interface.

Well, then tell your colleague to figure out what he wants. If you reimplement the interface, then any call to `DoSomething`, be it through a `Debug` typed reference or an `IDebug` typed reference, should call the reimplemented behavior. Any other behavior would be unexpected and deeply bewildering.

On the other hand, if you need to keep the orignal behavior of the base class if calling `DoSomething()` through a `IDebug` typed reference then *do not re-implement the interface*. What other alternative are you proposing?

Does this mean that you should know about what interfaces the base class implements? Well yes, of course. I find your question about why should anyone know what interfaces any given class you are going to inherit from implements deeply worrisome to be honest.

Comment: @Evk Of course it will change everything. `((IDebug)debug).DoSomething()` will call the explicit implementation, `debug.DoSomething()` wont.

Comment: Yes my comment about "no other differences" is misleading. But still, I think question is not about this. OP inherits some base class, wants to implement  IDebug interface and wants a warning if that interface is already implemented in base class, to not accidentally overwrite parent implementation.

Comment: "Simple don't do so". So are you saying that you're supposed to check all interfaces implemented by all classes? My colleague ran into this and didn't realize that the superclass also implemented that interface. The fact that it supposedly "assumes" that you know this, strikes me as odd, since you get a compile warning when you hide an implicit implementation. In my colleague's case, he said he _had_ to implement both the base class and the interface because it was an event-based interface.

Comment: @AskeB. The warning about the implicit implementation is a red herring. The warning has nothing to do with the interface, its simply a method hiding warning (see edits to my answer). And yes, if you inherit from a class you should know everything relevant about that class, that includes what interfaces it implements. Whats so bewildering about that?

Comment: @InBetween E.g. if there's 15 base classes inbetween the one that implements the interface, do you find it reasonable to expect that everyone checks the entire chain before implementing the interface? What about 150 classes? 1500 classes? Unreasonable numbers, but hopefully you see my point. Regardless, it means that you expect all programmers to have this on their todo list of things to keep in mind, instead of just having a compile warning.

Comment: @AskeB. Ask reasonable questions. If you have a chain of inheritance 15 deep, never mind 150, you've got bigger problems to contend with.

Comment: @InBetween You're not always in control of such things. If you're implementing an external library that already has 15 classes, what are you supposed to do? Stop using it and implement your own out of principle?

Comment: @AskeB.If you are using an exernal library, more the reason to know in detail *everything knowable* about the class you are going to inherit from. How deep or not the type hierarchy is should be a non factor here. I'm not sure where you are trying to go with all this.

Comment: The supposition of the hypothetical is "I've got a poorly designed hierarchy that is way too deep. I know what to do: let's make it deeper!"  Again, if it hurts when you do that, *don't do it*.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the external library is one of Xamarin's default libraries, which is owned by Microsoft. Even though an ideal world has omniscient developers, I still think you guys are arguing the wrong case here. To me you're arguing against the seatbelt because every driver should know to drive safely.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Explicit implementation than method is not visible in your class without casting to interface.
You will not be able to call

```
new ExternalClass().GetImportantInfo()
```

but you can call

```
((IDebug)new ExternalClass()).GetImportantInfo();
```

Because of Explicit implementation new keyword is not necessary. You could even add both implementations in one class:

```
    public class ExternalClass : IDebug
    {
        string IDebug.GetImportantInfo() //Explicit implementation
        {
            return "Explicit";
        }
        public string GetImportantInfo() 
        {
            return nameof(ExternalClass);
        }
    }
```

Additionally your Debug class does not have to inherit IDebug interface as it inherits ExternalClass. Resharper will show you this as redundant.

Comment: Yes - but the question is why I can hide the explicit implementation of the base class without getting a warning that I'm hiding it. If `Debug` doesn't implement `IDebug` and I call `test.GetImportantInfo();` as in the question, then the explicit implementation is called. I sadly don't have ReSharper currently, but regardless - if you want to implement your own implementation of a base class' implicit implementation, you can call `base.GetImportantInfo()`. When it's implemented explicitly in the base class, I won't have access to `base.GetImportantInfo()`

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)